# How to downloading public google drive files via powershell and execute them?

Tags: powershell, scripting, google-drive-api

DNS Filter is a publicly available tool, the script below links to an actual download of said .msi file.

```
#DNS Filter Variables
# $dnspath = "C:\Program Files\dnsfilter.msi";
# $dnsurl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1NE0W0-zDEejLjxUSVEAK5ZPx2sDGeRIZ&confirm=t";

Set execution policy to unrestricted
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser

Download DNS Filter
Write-Output "Downloading current DNS Filter file"
Invoke-RestMethod -uri $dnsurl -OutFile $dnspath
```

This powershell script used to work just fine, specifically the "&confirm=t" variable is what allowed the file to download via powershell while bypassing confirmation that normally comes up.  I believe sometime between November 2023 - Now (01/16/24), something changed on google drive's end that broke the script so it no longer downloads the file properly.

Unfortunately this script, is asking for confirmation, which previously it did not

Now when that script runs, it instead downloads an html file.  Which I have attached...

I cannot figure out how I need to modify the above url to once again begin bypassing the google drive confirmation.

Instead of downloading the file automatically (like it used to prior to 2024) This is the html file that gets downloaded in it's place:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Google Drive - Virus scan warning</title><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><style nonce="bsh8CEl2DcDV3mgd_h4mXA">.goog-link-button{position:relative;color:#15c;text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer}.goog-link-button-disabled{color:#ccc;text-decoration:none;cursor:default}body{color:#222;font:normal 13px/1.4 arial,sans-serif;margin:0}.grecaptcha-badge{visibility:hidden}.uc-main{padding-top:50px;text-align:center}#uc-dl-icon{display:inline-block;margin-top:16px;padding-right:1em;vertical-align:top}#uc-text{display:inline-block;max-width:68ex;text-align:left}.uc-error-caption,.uc-warning-caption{color:#222;font-size:16px}#uc-download-link{text-decoration:none}.uc-name-size a{color:#15c;text-decoration:none}.uc-name-size a:visited{color:#61c;text-decoration:none}.uc-name-size a:active{color:#d14836;text-decoration:none}.uc-footer{color:#777;font-size:11px;padding-bottom:5ex;padding-top:5ex;text-align:center}.uc-footer a{color:#15c}.uc-footer a:visited{color:#61c}.uc-footer a:active{color:#d14836}.uc-footer-divider{color:#ccc;width:100%}.goog-inline-block{position:relative;display:-moz-inline-box;display:inline-block}* html .goog-inline-block{display:inline}*:first-child+html .goog-inline-block{display:inline}sentinel{}</style><link rel="icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/drive_2022q3_32dp.png"/></head><body><div class="uc-main"><div id="uc-dl-icon" class="image-container"><div class="drive-sprite-aux-download-file"></div></div><div id="uc-text"><p class="uc-warning-caption">Google Drive can't scan this file for viruses.</p><p class="uc-warning-subcaption">This file is executable and may harm your computer. <p class="uc-warning-subcaption"><span class="uc-name-size"><a href="/open?id=1NE0W0-zDEejLjxUSVEAK5ZPx2sDGeRIZ">DNS_Agent_Setup.msi</a> (3.8M)</span></p></p><form id="download-form" action="https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download" method="get"><input type="submit" id="uc-download-link" class="goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-action" value="Download anyway"/><input type="hidden" name="id" value="1NE0W0-zDEejLjxUSVEAK5ZPx2sDGeRIZ"><input type="hidden" name="export" value="download"><input type="hidden" name="confirm" value="t"><input type="hidden" name="uuid" value="fbc7bc79-057c-4f5d-9882-73dc451e6f9c"></form></div></div><div class="uc-footer"><hr class="uc-footer-divider"></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Maybe the ID of your file has changed and you need to obtain it again? https://www.marstranslation.com/blog/how-to-skip-google-drive-virus-scan-warning-about-large-files

Comment: I already checked the ID, unfortunately it has not changed, so that is not the solution :(

Comment: It might be easier to use a different file storage or service (Google Drive is not meant for automated downloads like this). Google Cloud Storage could be an alternative but is also more involved.

Comment: I would like to do this through google drive if possible so I am going to leave the question open in case someone has figured out how to bypass that virus scanner confirmation as of 2024...

However maybe I should just modify the scripts to use an S3 bucket instead, at least for now.

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions:

- You could either zip the file or similar to change it to a non-executable format.
  `Expand-Archive` can take it from there.
- You could use the [`GoogleDrive` Module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/GMGoogleDrive/) to download the file without the warning

  ```
  $credential = Import-Clixml -Path "Path\To\ServiceAccountKey.json"
  Connect-GoogleDrive -Credential $credential Authenticate with a Google service account
  $file = Get-DriveFile -FileId "123456-zDEejLjxUSVEAK5ZPx2sDGeRIZ"
  Export-DriveFile -DriveFile $file -Path $dnspath
  ```

Comment: - The only problem with these two methods, is I run this script remotely on multiple systems... and after downloading 3 different apps, it proceeds to install them all remotely.
- So with option 1: I lose the ability to install remotely, or perhaps I simply need to add a extraction rule to the script so that the files once downloaded are extracted somewhere. 
- Option 2 would require me to install the google drive module on every system I intend to run this script on. –

Comment: Using the Drive Module is certainly more involved and probably not worth it if there is no other benefit to it. Un/Zipping the file should be manageable with this setup, though.

Comment: Yeah if there is no way to update the link to bypass that confirmation, I think zipping the file might be the best bet (assuming it doesn't trigger the same screen)  Thank you!

Comment: Using a zip file fixed the issue.
My full script is now working again, thank you!

Comment: Well, looks like it fixed the script for 1 of the 3 files. The file size is triggering that confirmation, which is breaking the script for my bigger files, a zip file did not resolve this for the bigger files (30 MB and 75MB)...  Unfortunately this means I am back to the drawing board unless I can figure out how to tell google to automatically confirm like prior to 2024.